# React Native: Dismiss the keyboard and remain the focus in the TextInput

Tags: react-native

I have tried all the methods, but when i dismiss the keyboard the focus also blur. But when I wanna user to paste the information to the TextInput i am not willing to show the soft keyboard.

```
<TextInput
    ref='barcodeInput'
    style={{height: 60,borderColor: '#000000', borderWidth: 1, width:300, fontSize:30}}
    underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
    onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({inputBarcode:text})}
    onSubmitEditing={this.handleSubmitEditing.bind(this)}
    keyboardType = {'numeric'}
/>
```

Comment: Was a solution ever found for this? I find it crazy that the notion of blurring textinput was baked into `keyboard.dismiss` without giving the option to prevent that behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `showSoftInputOnFocus` prop on `TextInput` to control the behavior.

> When `false`, it will prevent the soft keyboard from showing when the field is focused. The default value is `true`.

Docs: https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#showsoftinputonfocus

When this prop is `false`, the keyboard will not open, but the input will remain focused.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30896337)

Answer (score -4):

You should be able to use the `Keyboard` component from `react-native`. Eg:

```
import { Keyboard } from 'react-native'
Keyboard.dismiss()
```

The focus should still be kept on your input, but the soft keyboard will disappear.

Comment: this doesn't work for me. Keyboard.dismiss() hide keyboard but also remove focus. There is any especial way to use?

Comment: This answer is not valid, RN's documentation says the opposite for `dismiss` function: [`Dismisses the active keyboard and REMOVES focus`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/keyboard.html#dismiss).